# Error while connecting to mysql database using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting below exception from my DAO class

```
baseDataList=new JdbcTemplate().query(sql, rowMapper);
```

Caused by:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified

I have already declared all the properties related to DB connection in my `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Avoid writing 
    `new JdbcTemplate();`, instead inject it using:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
.
.
.
@Resource
private JdbcTemplate template;
```

Also, add property file's details if this doesn't work.

Spring helps taking away the creational dependency i.e. we should not use any "new" operation rather let spring inject whatever is required. (dependency injection) 
Its a good practice to inject the beans and let spring take care of the rest to be more flexible.
Thats the beauty of dependency injection.